# How to stop a function if an alert is called?

Tags: javascript

I'm a very beginner to JavaScript, and am working on adding some functionality to a pre-coded exercise learned the other day at a Meetup. This is a "virtual pet" with the ability to be given treats, played with, or exercised. Each click of these buttons triggers the increment up or down on their weight or happiness.
When either of these reaches 0, an alert is called that the pet is too skinny or too unhappy...but I'm still able to increment down the OTHER condition. 
As someone pretty inexperienced, what would be the simplest way to ensure that if weight or happiness reaches 0, it will throw the alert and prevent you from simply clicking "Okay" and continuing to increment down the other?

Here is what I'm working on in CodePen:
https://codepen.io/HeyOliveHey/pen/wmGmRj

```
var pet_info = {
name: "Poodle",
weight: 45,
happiness: 4
}

$(function() {

  // Called function to update the name, happiness, and weight of our pet in our HTML
  checkAndUpdatePetInfoInHtml();

  // When each button is clicked, it will "call" function for that button (functions are below)
  $('.treat-button').click(clickedTreatButton);
  $('.play-button').click(clickedPlayButton);
  $('.exercise-button').click(clickedExerciseButton);

})

  // Add a variable "pet_info" equal to a dictionary with the name (string), weight (number), and happiness (number) of your pet

  function clickedTreatButton() {
    pet_info.happiness = pet_info.happiness += 1;
    // Increase pet happiness
    pet_info.weight = pet_info.weight += 1;
    // Increase pet weight
    checkAndUpdatePetInfoInHtml();
  }

  function clickedPlayButton() {
        pet_info.happiness += 1;
        pet_info.weight -=1;

    // Increase pet happiness
    // Decrease pet weight
    checkAndUpdatePetInfoInHtml();
  }

  function clickedExerciseButton() {
    pet_info.happiness -=1;
    pet_info.weight -=1;
    // Decrease pet happiness
    // Decrease pet weight
    checkAndUpdatePetInfoInHtml();
  }

  function checkAndUpdatePetInfoInHtml() {
    checkWeightAndHappinessBeforeUpdating();  
    updatePetInfoInHtml();
  }

  function checkWeightAndHappinessBeforeUpdating() {
    if (pet_info.weight < 0) {
        pet_info.weight = 0;   
          alert("Your dog is too skinny, feed it now.")
    }
    if (pet_info.happiness < 0) {
        pet_info.happiness = 0;
          alert("Your dog isn't happy, play with it or give it a treat.")
    }
    // Add conditional so if weight is lower than zero, set it back to zero
  }

  // Updates your HTML with the current values in your pet_info dictionary
  function updatePetInfoInHtml() {
    $('.name').text(pet_info['name']);
    $('.weight').text(pet_info['weight']);
    $('.happiness').text(pet_info['happiness']);
  }
```

Comment: `pet_info.happiness = pet_info.happiness += 1` can be shortened to `pet_info.happiness += 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your `checkWeightAndHappinessBeforeUpdating()` function return a value. So:

```
function checkWeightAndHappinessBeforeUpdating() {
    var valid = true;
    if (pet_info.weight < 0) {
        valid = false;
        pet_info.weight = 0;   
          alert("Your dog is too skinny, feed it now.")
    }
    if (pet_info.happiness < 0) {
        valid = false;
        pet_info.happiness = 0;
          alert("Your dog isn't happy, play with it or give it a treat.")
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Then you can make decisions based on the return value. So in `checkAndUpdatePetInfoInHtml`:

```
function checkAndUpdatePetInfoInHtml() {
    if (checkWeightAndHappinessBeforeUpdating()) {
        updatePetInfoInHtml();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to set the relevant buttons to be disabled depending on the conditions.

```
 $(".exercise-button").attr("disabled", true);
```

So you would place a line similar to this immediately after your alerts that disables the appropriate buttons and then you'll need to do also set them to be enabled once the conditions are correct.